# Error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." when trying to query data from multiple google sheets workbooks

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The formula works when pulling from just 2 separate workbooks but when adding the 3rd I get this error, I have 15+ more separate workbooks to pull from. All workbook tables I am pulling in are formatted with the same column headers and number of columns in the same order.

I would also like to filter blanks so that I can allow for additional rows of data to be pulled into the aggregate workbook dynamically.

Is there a better way to go about this?

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("URL","SheetName!A2:J");IMPORTRANGE("URL","SheetName!A2:J");IMPORTRANGE("URL","SheetName!A2:J")},"select * where Col1<>''")

Comment: 1. First and foremost troubleshooting step is to try each importrange formula separately and make sure the data is being imported in rightfully. 2. also its bound to fail in general if one(or multiple) sheets you are trying to vertical stack has NO data et all, I mean like an empty dataset 3. wrap the empty(or all) datasets in foolproof way as `iferror(importrange(),wraprows(,10,))` 10 being the column count of *A:J*